# What is the proper return type to build?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, stack

My build fails. I'm not sure why...

> Introduction: For  this  assignment  you  have  to write  a  c  program  that  will  take  an  infix expression  as  input  and  display  the  postfix  expression  of  the  input.  After  converting to the postfix expression, the program should evaluate the expression from the postfix and display the result.

We have to use stacks for this and I already can't build the first stack dynamically allocated.

```
typedef struct stack
{
    int top;
    int capacity;
    int *arr;

} stack;

stack* createStack(int capacity) //create a stack, must allocate a box of memory of pointer to that stack
{
    stack* s = malloc(sizeof(stack)*1);
    s->top = -1; //bc it's a pointer, use an arrow or (*s).top;
    s-> capacity = capacity;   //one's a pointer, one's what's 
          //passed to it
    s-> arr = malloc(sizeof(char)* capacity);
     //defensive coding: checks to see if we found space for the 
                     //array
     if(s->arr == NULL)
     {
        printf("Failed to find space for the array.\n");
        free(s);
        return NULL;
      }
    else
        return s;
}
```

Comment: *"My build fails. I'm not sure why"* it would be helpful if you provided the error generated on failure.

Comment: You said that the compilation or linking failed... I presume you got an error message - it is imperative that you add the error message into the question itself

Comment: ... and "What is the proper return type to build?" does not really indicate what your problem or question is - it is rather meaningless I am afraid.

Comment: The code you have posted compiles without error (although it does contain semantic errors) - if compiled as C code (make sure you have not built it as C++ in error).  Are you sure that your build error is related to this code?  Perhaps it is calls to this code that are erroneous?  Perhaps it is a linker error and you have not correctly linked your code.  Your toolchain outputs _diagnostic_ messages for a reason - to aid diagnostics; we are at a disadvantage if you do not include that diagnostic information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have integer pointer `int *arr;` but into your code you have allocated less memory `s-> arr = malloc(sizeof(char)* capacity);`

instead you should write:
`s-> arr = malloc(sizeof(int)* capacity);`

Comment: While a valid comment, that error would bot cause a build error which appears to be what the question is about.  You've perhaps answered the _next question_ ;-)